# Random text output using FloatingButton (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Need to output a random item from a list when I tap on the FloatingButton on the Text Widget. Tried many methods online but none seem to work.

Example:
I have 5 tasks:
Eat a sandwich
Take a nap
Call your friend
Run a kilometre
Buy some flowers.

Now, on a button press, I want one task displayed, like:

Your task is...
Call your friend.

Created a new list.dart file with list of items as well.

First post here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show what you're exactly trying to do by code or output example.

Comment: Hey Anthony, welcome to the community. To enable us to help you, post the relevant code you have written.

Comment: Gave an example that should help. Away from my desktop for now, so can't post the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a random number generator to get a random number between 0 and the length of the list.

```
import 'dart:math';

...

final listItem = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]; /// the list which has tasks

final String randomString = '';  /// initially defined as empty

...

Text(randomString),           /// example widget where task is to be displayed

...

onTap: () {
  // function called when there's a tap on the FloatingButton

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomIndex = random.nextInt(listItems.length); // where listItems is the list in list.dart file

    final randomItem = listItems[randomIndex]; /// random item required
    
    setstate((){
      randomString = randomItem;
    });
}
```

Comment: This works only for numbers. I'm looking for something that works for sentences on the tap of a button.

Comment: This randomItem is your text. You can display it in your `Text()` widget.

Comment: This seems logical. The only error I am getting now is for randomString, where it says - The getter 'randomString' isn't defined for the class '_MyAppState'.

Comment: define a string variable `randomString` in your class.

Comment: I get a null safety error for the text widget when I do that

Comment: @AnthonyStephenMendes I've given the basic logic and code snippet to go forward. Other errors you're getting are not related to this. Please check how to resolve null safety. It's using `?`. I can only help you with the general answer not do the full code on your behalf.